# Error: A CMake tool must be setup for building. Configure a CMake tool in the kit options

Tags: c++, cmake, qt-creator

While using QT Creator, I'm getting this error. I would really appreciate some help in understanding this error, as I've setup the CMake tool in the QT creator, and yet it perhaps isn't finding it. Here is the error:

```
A CMake tool must be setup for building. Configure a CMake tool in the kit options
```

Here are some details about my environment:

- OS: Windows 10 64 bit
- QT Creator 4.10
- CMake 3.16.0

Please let me know what more information you'd require and I shall edit the question accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error is documented at length in this [QT Creator bug thread](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-18530), and appears to affect QT Creator versions 4.3.0 through 4.10. Several posts in the thread list work-arounds for the issue, including simply restarting QT Creator. Others on the thread suggested the following work-around to avoid the error:

- Edit your CMake files in an *external* editor (outside QT Creator)
- Then, run CMake from QT Creator

If you want the error removed completely, a fix was implemented in [QT Creator 4.11](https://www.qt.io/blog/qt-creator-4.11-beta-released).

Comment: I see. Thank you. i did go through some threads but did not come across this one. Thanks anyway.